# How can I get authorization token in rest API using rest assured? Is it possible?

Tags: rest, token

Currently using Postman I have to do post request to API_URL/login and I pass username and password and in return i get token see below:

Example Request:

```
/login
POST
Body
{
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "admin"
}
Return
{
    "token": "1234-56789-..."
}
```

Can you tell me how would I do .. i tried using .parameters but it says deprecated...

Comment: @Test
    public void testStatusCode(){
     
     String response =
                given()
                    .parameters("username", "wahmed", "password", "wahmed123")
                    .auth()
                    .preemptive()
                .when()
                    .post("/oauth/token")
                    .asString();

        JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(response);
        String accessToken = jsonPath.getString("access_token");

     
    }
}

Comment: @Test
    public void testStatusCode(){
     /*
     RestAssured.baseURI = System.getProperty("http://qa-takehome.dev.aetion.com:4440/login");
     PreemptiveBasicAuthScheme authScheme = new PreemptiveBasicAuthScheme();
     authScheme.setUserName("wahmed");
     authScheme.setPassword("wahmed123");
     RestAssured.authentication = authScheme;
     */
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to know what the schema is of the response.    For instance, if the output is like thus:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "authorization_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJCZWFy...",
    "refresh_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJCZWFyZ...",
    "type": "Bearer",

    ...
}
```

Knowing the schema, you can extract the entire output and parse through it, like thus:

```
import io.restassured.response.Response;

Response response =  
        RestAssured.given().
            header("Content-Type", "application/json").
            body(loginPayload).
        when().
            post("/login").
        then().
            log().ifError().
            statusCode(200).
            contentType("application/vnd.api+json").
            body("$", hasKey("authorization_token")).                                   //authorization_token is present in the response
            body("any { it.key == 'authorization_token' }", is(notNullValue())).        //authorization_token value is not null - has a value
        extract().response();
```

The auth token could then be set to a string variable

```
String auth_token = response.path("authorization_token").toString();
```

extract().response(); returns the entire reponse, but you could change this to extract().path("authorization_token") for just single string

Comment: I can get get token Now I dont understand how can i pass this to create user can I add multiple key:value in header?
 public void createUser1(){
Response response= RestAssured.given().header("Content-Type", "application/json").body(post).when().post("http://qa-takehome.dev.aetion.com:4440/user").then().log().ifError().statusCode(200).contentType("application/json").body("$", hasKey("email")).                                   body("any { it.key == 'email' }", is(notNullValue())).extract().response();
 String resp_email = response.path("email").toString();
 System.out.println(resp_email);}

Comment: Response response =  
          RestAssured.given().
           auth().
           oauth2(auth_token).
              header("Content-Type", "application/json").
              body(post).
          when().
              post("http://qa-takehome.dev.aetion.com:4440/user").
          then().
              log().ifError().
              statusCode(200).
              contentType("application/json").
              body("$", hasKey("email")).                                   
              body("any { it.key == 'email' }", is(notNullValue())).        
          extract().response();

Answer (score 1):

REST Assured supports mapping Java objects to/from JSON. You just need a JSON parser such as Jackson or Gson on the classpath.

First define a class to represent the user credentials:

```java
class Credentials {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Then define class to represent the authentication token:

```java
class AuthenticationToken {

    private String token;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

And finally perform the request to exchange the credentials for the token:

```java
@Test
public void authenticate() {

    Credentials credentials = new Credentials();
    credentials.setUsername("admin");
    credentials.setPassword("password");

    AuthenticationToken authenticationToken =

        given()
            .accept("application/json")
            .contentType("application/json")
            .body(credentials)
        .expect()
            .statusCode(200)
        .when()
            .post("/login")
        .then()
            .log().all()
            .extract()
                .body().as(AuthenticationToken.class);

    assertNotNull(authenticationToken.getToken());
}
```

Comment: .post("/auth") has to be replaced by .post("http://qa-takehome.dev.aetion.com:4440/login")

Comment: If I have to use this token in subsquent method how can I do that? The setter in AutehnticationToken class is taking String paramter whereas this is in json format? Do i need to convert first ? Do i need to declare AuthenticationToken variable globally as this will be used in susbsequent methods as well?

Comment: @WaheedAhmed First of all, you should spend a few moments reading the [REST Assured documentation](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage). Second, my answer aims to give you a guidance on how to perform the authentication and not a full-copy-and-paste-solution. Understand what the code does and then use it in your project. If you need the token in a new request, store the token in a variable and use it...