# How to automate an API call that requires a token from firebase?

Tags: java, rest, api, testing, automation

I'm currently having trouble automating an API call that requires token to work.

This API, if ran through Postman - demands a token to work. I'm able to get the token through the web console and just use that in Postman.

This is the exact stuff that I want to get automated using **RestAssured**.
I'm looking for blocks of code to do this, but can't seem to find any working solution.

It this helps also, we're using Firebase to authorize users that try to log-in on our app.

Let me know if there are still infos that need to be supplied to answer this question.

Thank you very much!

Tried watching youtube tutorial but it's written in Gherkin and I'm not knowledgeable at all with Gherkin.

Also there were tutorials that talks about authorization but I believe it does not fit the scenario I'm currently dealing with.

Comment: have you tried the second answer of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790021/rest-assured-bearer-authentication

Comment: I think that 2nd answer used Gherkin commands?

Comment: Have you looked at the question [How can I get authorization token in rest API using rest assured? Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45188549/how-can-i-get-authorization-token-in-rest-api-using-rest-assured-is-it-possible)?